# ValueError : Expecting ',' delimiter:

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi3, delimiter, valueerror

Hello I'm trying to collect data from an electricity meter that as a smart module attached to it.

I have a problem to fetch the data from the JSON file.
Here is below my MYDATA.JSON file:

```
{   
     "consobase":~LG526 1 12005$
}
```

If I open my browser and go to the corresponding file with its IP adress (XXX.XXX.XX.XX/mydata.json). I can see the right information I need :

```
{   
    "consobase":001046883
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the data with a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ in Python so here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import time

while True:
    url = requests.get('http://169.254.64.35/mydata.json')

    energy = json.loads(url.text)

    print energy['consobase'], 'kWh'

    time.sleep(5)
```

When I try to execute the program I have the following error message displayed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo python envoie_db_energy_total.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "envoie_db_energy_total.py", line 8, in <module>
    energy = json.loads(url.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 15 (char 18)
```

Do you have any idea on how I can solve the problem? I have looked around on internet but didn't find anything relevant to help me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check http://www.json.org. Your *json* is malformed: e.g. *~LG526 1 12005$* should be enclosed by *dblquotes* (***"***). It's like (and you can test it) `json.loads('{     "consobase":~LG526 1 12005$}')`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you call your Python script with `sudo`? Also, how is `~LG526 1 12005$` related to `001046883`?

Comment: Thank you @CristiFati ! I have enclosed `~LG526 1 12005$` with _dblquotes_ and now it works for my program. @tobias_k I'm a beginner in Raspberry Pi so that's why I'm using sudo everytime. Like that when I want to lauch a program it always works. `~LG526 1 12005$` is reaching an adress of my ecodevice I guess and like that it fetch the total electrical consumption. Since it has been installed, I have consumed 1046.883 kWh.